# Bootstrap or Foundation ? Which goes well with CQ?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, aem

We have an option to use either Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation in out CQ project. I am not sure  but CQ OOTB components are more compatible with foundation or Bootstrap ?

I am aware this is not much of a constructive question but I just needed this information if anyone has a comparison in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mobile is a huge concern use Foundation. If it's secondary use Twitter Bootstrap. Foundation is for "Mobile First". Bootstrap is for generic web development and some extra jquery sugar. If you need that jquery sugar use bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah... I don't think mobile will be such a huge concern.. but yes.. a general responsive design for PC, tablet and mobile is needed

Comment: Then use Foundation. It'll be easier to maintain in the long run. Bootstrap isn't ideal for mobile. Bootstrap 3 will be mobile first, but for now foundation has the edge.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We finalized to use foundation !